# Friend claims $\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^{(n+1)^sx^{n+1}}+1}dx=\zeta(s+1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, closed-form

My friend is making another claim on another integral!

**Can anybody verify it? Or his is mocking on me?**

Valid  for all $s\ge1$

$$\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^{(n+1)^sx^{n+1}}+1}dx=\zeta(s+1)$$

Where $\zeta(s)$ is the Zeta function defined for all $R(s)>1$

$$\zeta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+1)^s}$$

---

I think this integral is fault because, most integral with $\zeta(s)$ involves an $e^x$ at the denominator or a $\ln(x)$. This integral has none of these. I also check maths world and other sites but couldn't an integral similar to it.

Comment: Change friends....

Comment: Letting the sum and integral go to 20 instead of infinity, and letting $s=1$, I get 1.59, so it might be true.

Comment: Lol I will. He is an annoying person, but it is bother me. I have to know the answer

Comment: @DonAntonio. I went to your profile. I am very sorry ! Many people here will miss you. Cheers.

Comment: For your next questions, let me suggest to slow down on the "one friend asked me this" folklore and to concentrate more on the maths content. This way, we might start to read some context and/or personal input, two things your questions are until now quite empty of.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Dear Claude: nice people like you, and others as well, are the ones that make this site still worth...barely, but still. Salute, mon ami. From time to time I shall still participate.

Comment: @DonAntonio. I hope and wish you do.! Hasta muy pronto, amigo !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**. One may just interchange sum and integration :
$$
\int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^{(n+1)^sx^{n+1}}+1}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{2^{(n+1)^sx^{n+1}}+1}dx
$$ then, by the change of variable $$u=(n+1)^sx^{n+1}, \quad du=(n+1)^{s+1}x^ndx,$$ one gets
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{x^n}{2^{(n+1)^sx^{n+1}}+1}dx=\frac1{(n+1)^{s+1}}\int_0^\infty\frac1{2^u+1}du=\frac1{(n+1)^{s+1}} \times 1 =\frac1{(n+1)^{s+1}},
$$ giving

> $$
> \int_0^\infty\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{2^{(n+1)^sx^{n+1}}+1}dx=\zeta(s+1),\quad s\geq1,
> $$

as announced.

Comment: Simple and nice proof, I learn a lot from your proof. I just wonder how do you know when to use what substitution or it just it comes with your nature ability?

Comment: Here the factor $x^n$ made me think of the derivative of $x^{n+1}$: $(x^{n+1})'=(n+1) \times x^n$, that was the starting point. Thank you.